# ARM64 in cpuArchitecture and no Task Running

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, task, amazon-ecs

I am using terraform to create my architecture.
Adding the following rows on the resource ecs_task_definitions

```
“runtimePlatform”: {
    “operatingSystemFamily”: “LINUX”,
    “cpuArchitecture”: “ARM64”
 },
```

The task does not run. This is the error

> STOPPED (CannotPullContainerError: inspect image has been retried 1 time(s): failed to resolve ref "********.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ecr-repo-prod:latest": **********.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ecr-repo-prod:latest: not found)

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: This error means Docker image on such ECR registry address with such name and tag was not found

Comment: Why did you include the information about `ARM64` in your question exactly? Did you just recently change the `cpuArchitecture` setting on your ECS task? If so, did you build a new docker image that targets the ARM platform?

Comment: I need arm64 because I am testing for another architecture... Do you know how to build the docker image with two target platforms? Can I have an example please?